# Can I reuse the cucumber steps for multiple scenarios?? Is it legal to use the same hook file across different features?

Tags: protractor, cucumber, hook

Can I reuse the cucumber steps for multiple scenarios??

I'm facing the following issues:

1) If the same step is repeated in 2 scenarios, execution fails.

```
Feature: LoginPage Cases
@smoke @regression
Scenario: Login to the website with North America credentials
And Enter the username and password
|username |password|
|natester@outlook.com|456123 |
And I click the 'SignIn' button
Then I should see 'Successfully Logged in' message

@smoke @regression
Scenario: Login to the website with Europe credentials
And Enter the username and password
|username |password|
|eutester@outlook.com|456123 |
And I click the 'SignIn' button
Then I should see 'Successfully Logged in' message
```

Errors msgs are either:
No element found using locator OR Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page.

2) Cannot execute 2 different feature file together. I load the website from hooks file before each scenario. Scenarios in both the feature files need this the site to load before executing the scenario.

The features successfully execute when run independently while one of the feature fails if both run together as the website doesnt load for the second feature. Error message same as above.

```
Feature: LoginPage Cases
@smoke @regression
Scenario: Login to the website with North America credentials
And Enter the username and password
|username |password|
|natester@outlook.com|456123 |
And I click the 'SignIn' button
Then I should see 'Successfully Logged in' message

Feature: To work with SignUp page

@smoke @regression
Scenario: Load Sign Up Page 
And I click the 'Create a new Account' button
Then I should see the heading 'Create Account'
```

Can anyone help me understand if I'm dong something wrong??

Comment: May I ask what your code is to navigate to the website?

Comment: `registerHandler('BeforeScenario', async () => {
        console.log("Loading Website before scenario!!");
        await browser.get(config.baseUrl);
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
    });  `  baseURL being defined in the config file.

Comment: @protractortester Are you logging out before trying a second login?

Comment: No.  I will try that and see if it helps